# Why specify the path in app.use?

Tags: node.js, express

```
//app.js
var app = require('express')();
app.use('/test', require('./test'));



//test/index.js
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send("success");
});
module.exports = routes;
```

Why does the path need to be specified in app.use and router.get? If I simply put `app.use('/', require('./test'));` instead, it seems to work just fine still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With specifying  `router.get('/test', function (req, res)` your handler method will handle any request thats ends in /test. Depends on where the router is `use()`.

> app.use(withPath, [callback...]

That mount your middleware functions `tests` at the speficied path `/test`
So your middlewares `test` will be execute when the base request url path match.

Answer (score 2):

If you change this:

```
app.use('/test', require('./test'));
```

to this:

```
app.use('/', require('./test'));
```

then you will have the same functionality as before of using the middleware exported by the `./test` module on the routes that start with `/test` so you will experience that everything will work the same, but that middleware will also handle every other route not necessarily starting with `/test` which, depending on what it does and how it works, may or may not be what you want.

By using some path in the `app.use()` call you restrict the middleware that you're loading to that path only. When you use `/` then it's like saying "every path" because every path starts with the slash - even paths that are requested for URLs that doesn't include the slash are still requested with slash, using e.g. with HTTP/1.1 something like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
```